# React not passing props to child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, react-router-dom

I am new to React, and trying to set up a basic CRUD application as an example.

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/github/rytoplay/consume-restful-api-react?file=src%2FApp.js)

In the case of my

```
<EditProduct 
   products     = {this.state.products} 
   handleSubmit = {this.handleProductUpdate} />
```

component tag, an empty products[] array is being passed to props. I know state.products is populated because it passes to the `<Product>` component and I can see it in the console. I thought this might be an async problem but this happened even when I used mock data.

My 2nd problem is I am unable to extract the `:id` from the route when `http://localhost:3000/update/5e3615179d7a8e01d85147e1` is called so that I can filter the correct product out of the state.products[] and pass only the selected product down to `<EditProduct>`.  The useParams() function of react-router-dom isn't returning any results for me.
I know that I only need to pass one product, but I am also having trouble extracting the value of /:id from the route.

I've found CRUD tutorials, but not using the router like this. I don't see why that would cause this issue. I've been working on this for days. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Rob

Comment: To see the problem, click "Update" on any product and open the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `document.location.replace`, it's basically a page reload, which will unmount your `App` component and remount it again (you can check by putting console in `componentDidMount` in `App` component), which means `EditProduct` will receive your initial state again (which is empty array), before it's re-rendered with updated data. However, in constructor you'll only receive initial state.

My suggestion is to use `Link` component provided by `react-router-dom` to avoid page reload. [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-hfxgv2?file=src/components/products.js)

As for `useParams`, it's an API of `react-router-dom` that support [React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) API, which only works in Functional Components, not Class Components.